# Sass function renders as 1 long string

Tags: css, sass

I was playing around a bit with sass functions for text-shadows but haven't managed to get 1 to work. They all just render in 1 long string:

```
@function makelongshadow($color) {
  $val: 0px 0px $color;
  @for $i from 1 through 100 {
    $val: #{$val}, -#{$i}px #{$i}px #{$color};
  }
  @return $val;
}
```

Renders as:

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px #3e3e40-1px 1px #3e3e40-2px 2px #3e3e40-3px 3px #3e3e40-4px 4px #3e3e40-5px 5px #3e3e40-6px 6px #3e3e40-7px 7px #3e3e40-8px 8px #3e3e40-9px 9px #3e3e40-10px 10px #3e3e40-11px 11px #3e3e40-12px 12px #3e3e40-13px 13px #3e3e40-14px 14px #3e3e40-15px 15px #3e3e40-16px 16px #3e3e40-17px 17px #3e3e40-18px 18px #3e3e40-19px 19px #3e3e40-20px 20px #3e3e40-21px 21px #3e3e40-22px 22px #3e3e40-23px 23px #3e3e40-24px 24px #3e3e40-25px 25px #3e3e40-26px 26px #3e3e40-27px 27px #3e3e40-28px 28px #3e3e40-29px 29px #3e3e40-30px 30px #3e3e40-31px 31px #3e3e40-32px 32px #3e3e40-33px 33px #3e3e40-34px 34px #3e3e40-35px 35px #3e3e40-36px 36px #3e3e40-37px 37px #3e3e40-38px 38px #3e3e40-39px 39px #3e3e40-40px 40px #3e3e40-41px 41px #3e3e40-42px 42px #3e3e40-43px 43px #3e3e40-44px 44px #3e3e40-45px 45px #3e3e40-46px 46px #3e3e40-47px 47px #3e3e40-48px 48px #3e3e40-49px 49px #3e3e40-50px 50px #3e3e40-51px 51px #3e3e40-52px 52px #3e3e40-53px 53px #3e3e40-54px 54px #3e3e40-55px 55px #3e3e40-56px 56px #3e3e40-57px 57px #3e3e40-58px 58px #3e3e40-59px 59px #3e3e40-60px 60px #3e3e40-61px 61px #3e3e40-62px 62px #3e3e40-63px 63px #3e3e40-64px 64px #3e3e40-65px 65px #3e3e40-66px 66px #3e3e40-67px 67px #3e3e40-68px 68px #3e3e40-69px 69px #3e3e40-70px 70px #3e3e40-71px 71px #3e3e40-72px 72px #3e3e40-73px 73px #3e3e40-74px 74px #3e3e40-75px 75px #3e3e40-76px 76px #3e3e40-77px 77px #3e3e40-78px 78px #3e3e40-79px 79px #3e3e40-80px 80px #3e3e40-81px 81px #3e3e40-82px 82px #3e3e40-83px 83px #3e3e40-84px 84px #3e3e40-85px 85px #3e3e40-86px 86px #3e3e40-87px 87px #3e3e40-88px 88px #3e3e40-89px 89px #3e3e40-90px 90px #3e3e40-91px 91px #3e3e40-92px 92px #3e3e40-93px 93px #3e3e40-94px 94px #3e3e40-95px 95px #3e3e40-96px 96px #3e3e40-97px 97px #3e3e40-98px 98px #3e3e40-99px 99px #3e3e40-100px 100px #3e3e40
```

No ',' no breaks no ';' to close. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Really can't find it...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And are your file extensions .sass or .scss? And what version of sass are you using to compile it?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code. It seems to work.

Look at this [gist](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/9ad752df5f198536a4babdcfe3ca3f7e). 
Try updating sass/compass